# "display" view is not visible in any perspective in "Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.9.6.RELEASE"

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, perspective, spring-tools-4

Window -> Show view -> other -> type "disp". but display view is not coming[image]

I have done reset in both debug and spring prespective but still display is not visible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In 'Spring Tool Suite 4' same can be done via 'Debug Shell'. To add go
>   to window -> show view -> other -> 'Debug Shell' (instead of 'Display').

[image]

[image]